# RequestContext and Ajax status in PrimeFaces

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I need to handle globally ajax responses. Everything works ok, out of the box, when I only want to call normal javascript action without any arguments. Than I can use p:ajaxStatus controll, and application behaves in a correct way.

What I actually now need to do, is to handle situation, when during ajax request there was externalContext.redirect() call. It happens only in one place in application, but it is called from many places. 
I was thinking, that I can for instance add callback param in RequestContext. But how can I access this param in javascript?

While watching in firebug, I can see that callbackParam is returned in json response, but how can I access this value in javascript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's been added as a property of default `args` object which is available in `oncomplete` context.

So, for example

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().addCallbackParam("foo", "bar");
```

is available as

```
oncomplete="console.log(args.foo)"
```

#### See also:

- [PrimeFaces `RequestContext` showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/requestContext.xhtml)

---

**Update**: as per the comments, that turns out to fail in `<p:ajaxStatus>`. I sugges to report it as a bug to PF guys, that the arguments are not available in `<p:ajaxStatus oncomplete>`. In the meanwhile, you can workaround it with the following script which is loaded by `<h:outputScript target="head">` inside the `<h:body>` (to guarantee that it's loaded *after* PrimeFaces script):

```
var originalPrimeFacesAjaxUtilsSend = PrimeFaces.ajax.AjaxUtils.send;
PrimeFaces.ajax.AjaxUtils.send = function(cfg) {
    var originalOncomplete = cfg.oncomplete;
    cfg.oncomplete = function() {
        ajaxStatusOncomplete.apply(this, arguments);

        if (originalOncomplete) {
            originalOncomplete.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    };
    originalPrimeFacesAjaxUtilsSend.apply(this, arguments);
};

function ajaxStatusOncomplete(xhr, status, args) {
    // Do your thing here.
}
```

Comment: Your answer is true for CommandButton, when ajax callback is handled in context of button. In AjaxStatus this approach does not work.

Comment: Reproduced. That's likely a bug in `<p:ajaxStatus>`. I'll look for a workaround and update the answer.

Comment: Thank You BalusC, You're answer is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks to Your solution, I achieved my goal. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

In p:ajaxStatus params available via PrimeFaces.ajax.Queue.xhrs
For example:

```
oncomplete="console.log(PrimeFaces.ajax.Queue.xhrs[0].pArgs.foo)"
```